# MX Record Host Name Change

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

I'm trying to set up my own email server, but am unsure what to change the MX record 'target' to. (I'm unclear if this is the correct terminology, hence the inverted commas.)

*I should say that I'm running the server on my Raspberry Pi from my own personal internet connection. This really is only for fun, I'm not trying to reinvent gmail! I also know that I have a dynamic IP with my provider so will need to keep updating the DNS records, but as I say, it's only for fun.*

For example:

- I have the domain name, mygreatdomain.com which is registered
  with OVH
- My own internet connection has the IP 999.999.999.999
- The Pi has the (default) hostname raspberrypi
- I've changed the DNS A record through OVH to 'link' that domain name with my IP. So I am able to use my browser to see whatever html that the Pi's webserver is outputting

What do I change the DNS MX target to?

I'm trying to fill in this box, but am not sure how to do so. Are there any other changes that I need to make to my set up to make this work?

[image: DNS record change]

Answer (score 0):

To cite [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), the MX record contains two values:

> PREFERENCE      A 16 bit integer which specifies the preference given
> to
> this RR among others at the same owner.  Lower values
> are preferred.
>
> EXCHANGE        A  which specifies a host willing to act
> as
> a mail exchange for the owner name.

That said, you need to specify a preference (commonly called priority), e.g. `0`, and a Domain name that clients using your mail exchange can resolve, e.g. `mail.mygreatdomain.com`.

Additionally, I recommend [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) on MX records.

Comment: So for the setup listed above, the MX record would be changed to, raspberrypi.mygreatdomain.com

Comment: Yes, i changed the example domain to match your question.

Comment: But you've also quoted the host as mail, not raspberrypi. Will this make a difference?

Comment: My answer ist just an example. You can choose your host names any way you want. Please read some documentation on DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

If your mail server is running on `mygreatdomain.com` - it's going to have the same IP `999.999.999.999` as your domain. When someone emails `you@mygreatdomain.com` it will look for your MX records, if no MX records are found it will use your A record to send the mail to. So you don't need an MX record, since you're using the same IP. Since you're learning, there's 100's of different things that you need to set up correctly to run a mail server, take a look at this page: [Email Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/)